# UTC DateTime back to Original datetime

Tags: c#, javascript, json, stringify

I have probably just stared at this too long...

I have a third-party datepicker (ASP/MVC) and I stringify the array of selected dates and pass it to the controller.

example:

- My browser is US EST time zone.
- I select 5/21/2013
- when I stringify it I get ["2013-05-21T04:00:00Z"] (UTC)
- I pass it back to the webserver that is in Us PST timezone
- I want to get it back to 5/21/2013 12:00:00AM

I know that this is meant to be midnight since it is from a timeless datepicker.

In c#, how do I convert this back to its original time? I am in PST but that should not matter.

Comment: What result you expect and which side you need to do conversion (assuming server side/C#)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - yes, server side. See my edited example.

Comment: BTW, your information is inconsistent - you have T04:00Z and (-0700) as timezone. As result you want midnight - sort of hard to get what you want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think it is inconsistent. The browser converts 5/21/2013 12:00:00am EST -> 2013-05-21T04:00:00Z UTC. Now I want to convert 2013-05-21T04:00:00Z UTC back to EST (I don't know the timezone but I know it was originally midnight).

Comment: You should be able to get date by simply truncating time (time portion < 1200) or I think incrementing day by 1 (for time > 12). I would not do it server side as it is lying... sending correct data from browser or at least [Date.getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) would be better. BTW browser's timezone is obviously not EST but EDT.

Comment: If you don't know the original timezone, then you can't do what you want reliably.  If you make the assumption that the offset is between -11:45 and +12:00 it will be cover most cases, but you'll get the wrong result for New Zealand, which is UTC+13:00 during their daylight saving time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, this is what I did but was hoping for an algorithm that anyone might be able to use. If my javascript was stronger i would have handled it on the web end, and still may. EST/EDT, semantics. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string date = "2013-05-21T04:00:00Z" ;
DateTime dt = Datetime.parse(date);
dt = dt.Date;
```

You will get the date component only, with the time component as midnight.
    I hope this satisfies your requirement.